# Converting multiple columns to categories in Pandas. apply?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a Dataframe. I want to convert a set of columns `to_convert` to categories.

I can certainly do the following:

```
for col in to_convert:
  df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

but I was surprised that the following does not return a dataframe:

```
df[to_convert].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'), axis=0)
```

which of course makes the following not work:

```
df[to_convert] = df[to_convert].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'), axis=0)
```

Why does [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (`axis=0`) return a Series even though it is supposed to act on the columns one by one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was just fixed in master, and so will be in 0.17.0, see the issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10354)

```
In [7]: df = DataFrame({'A' : list('aabbcd'), 'B' : list('ffghhe')})

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   A  B
0  a  f
1  a  f
2  b  g
3  b  h
4  c  h
5  d  e

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]: 
A    object
B    object
dtype: object

In [10]: df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))       
Out[10]: 
   A  B
0  a  f
1  a  f
2  b  g
3  b  h
4  c  h
5  d  e

In [11]: df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category')).dtypes
Out[11]: 
A    category
B    category
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that [since pandas 0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.23.0.html#dataframe-astype-performs-column-wise-conversion-to-categorical) you no longer `apply` to convert multiple columns to categorical data types. Now you can simply do `df[to_convert].astype('category')` instead (where `to_convert` is a set of columns as defined in the question).

Comment: It looks like there's a line needed here for this to be a complete example: `to_convert = ['parks', 'playgrounds', 'sports', 'roading']; 
df[to_convert] = df[to_convert].astype('category')`

Comment: @VickiB `to_convert` is a set of columns as in the question, added that line to clarify.

Comment: That's what I thought (with my comment)

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this trying to do it in Dask, note that the newer pandas way will not work. You will get a "list assignment not supported" error.
Instead use df.categorize()